# I need Recursive function for below XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<Root><TID>E</TID><EID>1234</EID><Name>suresh</Name><OID>12</OID></Root>
```

I need XSLT for above XML. Tips: output fixed length:

- TID is (1)
- EID(2-10)
- Filler(11-13)
- Name(14-20)
- OID (21-24)

Output will be:

```
E000001234   Suresh 0012
```

Number should be filled with 0000, string left padding remaining with spaces - Filler also space

Some one could you please help me on this

Comment: Output will be:
E000001234<3spaces>Suresh<one space>0012

Comment: See similar padding functions like http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-integer-to-length.html to implement your own one as needed. Not sure why you would need any recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:value-of select="TID"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(EID, '000000000')"/>
    <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Name, '       '), 1, 7)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(OID, '0000')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your answer. Here I have provided just required example in my real requirement - Filler be like 381-581 only spaces, and employee ID 9-25, in that case what would your suggestion? I'm thinking to create template 1) for string 2) for numbers and to keep on call those templates

Comment: I think the only thing you need is a variable with the maximum number of spaces you'll ever need. Then use `substring(concat(Name, $spaces, 1, N)` for the string values. You can use a similar variable to hold a bank of zeros, if necessary.

Comment: Yes its working fine. But how about filler 381-581th position need to fill with spaces? How code identify this is particular position ?

Comment: I see no difference between 3 spaces at position 11-13 and 201 spaces at position 381-581 and I would handle both the same way.

Comment: I want code to identify position wise.. suppose 1st to 10th place is Employee id means 0000012345 then 11th to 20th name means 'SURESH<4spaces>' next filler 21st to 50th position '<30 spaces>' then transaction code 51st to 52nd '0E' - How I write code to achieve this ? O/P:0000012345SURESH<4spaces><30spaces>0E

Comment: I'm using your code in real time xslt but confuse to identify position .. In my real time program 40 Fields are there, and calling for different position wise insert. here is the example code

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($TransactionCode, $Space), 1, 1)"/>
             
             
            <!-- UIS Customer number hard coded to '8215214' -String length (2-8) -->
            <xsl:variable name="UIS"> <text>8775777</text> </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($UIS, $FillNo), 1, 8)"/>            
            
            
            <!-- Employee number - Use SSN number - String length (9-19) --> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(wd:SSN, $FillNo), 1, 11)"/>

Comment: You do not need to identify position. A fixed-length file is built by putting together fixed-length values, one-by-one. -- Please do not post code in comments, it's unreadable. If necessary, ask a new question.

Comment: I'm using DT now, this logic (your logic) is working fine thank you very much for your time and for your help:)